# Scala Map with Either

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I need a `Map[String, Either[Seq[String], String]]` and it should be mutable (yeah i know about bad practice, but I'm still learning). So, when I try to define it like this:

```
 val map: Map[String, Either[Seq[String], String]] = mutable.HashMap("" -> Right(""))
```

I get an error

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String,scala.util.Right[Nothing,String]]
[error]  required: Map[String,Either[Seq[String],String]]
[error]   val map:Map[String,Either[Seq[String],String]] = mutable.HashMap("" -> Right(""))
```

How should I define it right?

Comment: How about HashMap("" -> Right[Seq[String],String]("")) - should work, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general when making mutable collections (or `var`s, or anything mutable), it's better to explicitly specify types in their creation. This is because mutable collections are invariant in the contained type, and inferring invariant types is unreliable.

So, you could write,

```
val map = mutable.HashMap[String,Either[Seq[String],String]]("" -> Right(""))
```

and this should give you the correct type.

Comment: Oh yeah, i just forgot about invariantion of mutable collection) Thank you)